# Can't install Sonar Plugin in Apatana3

Tags: eclipse, aptana, sonarqube

**Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.4.0.201304151603**
**Build: jenkins-studio3-rcp-master-269** (origin/master)

Current Sonar Eclipse Plugin using http://dist.sonar-ide.codehaus.org/eclipse/

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could
>   not be found.   Software being installed: Sonar Python Analyser
>   3.1.0.20130326-0955-RELEASE (org.sonar.ide.eclipse.pydev.feature.feature.group
>   3.1.0.20130326-0955-RELEASE)   Missing requirement: Embedded Sonar Runner 3.1.0.20130326-0955-RELEASE (org.sonar.ide.eclipse.runtime
>   3.1.0.20130326-0955-RELEASE) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.jdt.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Sonar Integration for Eclipse Core 3.1.0.20130326-0955-RELEASE (org.sonar.ide.eclipse.core 3.1.0.20130326-0955-RELEASE)
>       To: bundle org.sonar.ide.eclipse.runtime 0.0.0   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Sonar Integration for PyDev 3.1.0.20130326-0955-RELEASE (org.sonar.ide.eclipse.pydev 3.1.0.20130326-0955-RELEASE)
>       To: bundle org.sonar.ide.eclipse.ui 0.0.0   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Sonar Python Analyser 3.1.0.20130326-0955-RELEASE (org.sonar.ide.eclipse.pydev.feature.feature.group
>   3.1.0.20130326-0955-RELEASE)
>       To: org.sonar.ide.eclipse.pydev [3.1.0.20130326-0955-RELEASE]   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Sonar Integration for Eclipse 3.1.0.20130326-0955-RELEASE (org.sonar.ide.eclipse.ui 3.1.0.20130326-0955-RELEASE)
>       To: bundle org.sonar.ide.eclipse.core 0.0.0

Comment: Can you tell which version of Eclipse is your Aptana Studuo 3 based on?

Comment: Aptana Studio 3.4.2 is based on Eclipse Platform Version: 3.7.2.v20120207-1839-9gF7UHPDFxGjd-PqDr2jX_4yKaumkoHTz04_q-q

Comment: I get the exact same error trying to install this plugin in Eclipse Juno (SR2, Build 20130225-0426) .